# Is there any IP messenger for Linux (CentOS)?

Tags: centos, ip, messaging

Currently am using a Linux (CentOS) machine. Is there any IP messenger for CentOS like iptux and Gnome IP Messenger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iptux](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/09/17/instant-message-on-your-lan-with-iptux/) seems quite portable. You could compile it from sources and install it locally like for example [this tutorial tells you](http://geeksterminal.com/how-to-install-iptux/1106/).

Alternatively, you could manually download [a packaged version of iptux in rpm format](http://pkgs.org/download/iptux) and install it using the CentOS package manager.

```
rpm -i iptux-0.5.1-11.fc20.i686.rpm
```

Comment: Can you provide installation steps pls

Comment: Just follow the linked tutorial. Or download an rpm file from the second link, open a command line in the directory downloaded to and issue the installation command.

Comment: i downloaded from http://www.mediafire.com/download/275r6sq5nb1zc1j/iptux-0.5.2.zip.how to install this file

Comment: Follow the tutorial. Extract the file, open a terminal in the extracted directory and issue there `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.